# Is this a valid way to simplify my inherited classes?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have many Azure classes containing fields for date and modified by tracking. Fields such as:

```
[DisplayName("Created By")]
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Modified By")]
public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

I want to avoid repetition so I was considering creating a class to contain these such as this:

```
public class TableServiceEntityRowInfo : TableServiceEntity  
{
    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Modified By")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

For my data classes then instead of having them inherit from TableServiceEntity I would like to set these up as follows:

```
public class MyClass : TableServiceEntityRowInfo 
{

}
```

Is this a valid and sensible way to add additional information to the fields. The reason I am asking here is because I am planning to do this to a lot of classes and I want to ensure I do the right thing.

Comment: I'm not 100, but in general I try to inherit if the classes "IS A" of the parent.  In your case they sound more like a "HAS A" in which case I might group the related properties into a seperate class and expose that property on the classes that need this functionality i.e. MyClass has a property called EntityRowInfo containing your ModifiedBy, CreatedBy properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is valid and sensible.

If there are any Azure-specific concerns, I can't speak to that.

As for the comment about "IS A" vs "HAS A," I think it can safely be ignored here. Really, it almost comes down to naming style. You've named your base class `TableServiceEntityRowInfo` because it is a `TableServiceEntity` that *has* row information. What if you called it instead `AuditableTableServiceEntity` because it has fields for auditing. Now it is exactly the same, but you can claim that each of the inheriting classes *"IS A"* `AuditableTableServiceEntity`.

You may also want to mark your base class as `abstract` to be clear that it should not be instantiated, only inherited.

Comment: I like the naming very much and the comment about abstract. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will work fine in Azure as the TableServiceEntity that your class inherits from is just a very basic class with RowKey, PartitionKey and Timestamp properties.